# Unable to restore purchases from previous version of the same app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, updates, restore

I have prepared a new build for my client's app - brand new, redesigned app. Everything is cool except that users of the new version are reporting that they are unable to restore their old non-consumable products (purchased in the old app). To make things even more weird - they are able to restore the same products, but purchased in the new app.

I believe that there is no difference in restored transactions no matter if they have been purchased within this or previous version of app when bundle identifier stays the same. I have double checked in Testflight app (with live Apple Id for restore) that only one out of six purchased products is already being restored.

My question is have you ever had such a weird issue in your apps? Any hints on peculiarities related to restoring purchases from previous versions of the app? Is it a bug in SDK? Does it make sense at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Clients were using live Apple ID in TestFlight build, not in the live app. Even if you use live account on TestFlight build it still operates in sandbox, and products purchased in production environment wont appear in sandbox when you restore purchases.

Comment: Hi Maciek, i have the same issue, purchase works in TestFlight but Restore not. in TestFlight I use Live Apple ID but making restore or purchase I use sandbox Apple ID. did you have the same issue? how you resolve.